# Automating contour selection

Tags: arcgis-desktop, contour, arcgis-10.4

I'm working with a lot of vector contour data, and it's getting annoying just selecting by Z-Value.

Is there a tool/ model/ script that I can just enter my starting elevation and contour intervals and just have it spit out the selected features?

I'm Working with ArcGIS 10.4.

Comment: You need to provide more information. Which software are you using or do you have access to?

Comment: What's your GIS software you are using ? Your question is very general. You should explain your problem in more details.

Comment: Arcgis 10.4, sorry new to the site.

Comment: Select by attribute?

Answer (score 1):

If the data is stored in the same layer you could define a query on the layer properties.
Your query should be something like:

> 

elevation >= 100 and elevation <= 500

> 

being "elevation" the field containing the value of the contour and "100,500" the min and max contours for display.

In case you need a sub-selection inside your dataset based on an interval, you can follow the next steps:

1.Add a new dBase table.
2.Create a field containing your intervals.
3.Create a sequence ad hoc. More info: http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000011137
4.Join the new table containing the interval field with your feature class containing the contours to be selected.
5.Select by Attributes on your Joined field where “Your_att” IS NOT NULL

With that steps you will get the selection. Another option is to create the interval table list on Excel or another software, open it in ArcMap and follow the rest of the steps.

I hope to be clear. If something needs a better explanation, I will be happy to help.

Comment: This is helpful, however my problem is that the data I get is usually in intervals of 5m. Depending on the project, I need it displayed at 20m or sometimes or 30m intervals. What I'm trying to do is, Start at z value ___ then grab every contour at ___ intervals.